# Add css link to HTML of HtmlHelper extension method

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-helper, pagedlist, urlhelper

I have a HtmlHelper extension method as below. It returns an instance of `PagedList.Mvc.HtmlHelper.PagedListPager`.

The PagedListRenderOptions have specified some css classes. Each view that uses this method needs to add a link to the css file containing the styles. Im finding this repetitive and redundant.

Is there a way I could add the css to the MvcHtmlString instance that is being returned here?

```
public static MvcHtmlString PagedListPagerCustom(this HtmlHelper helper, UrlHelper Url, PagedList.IPagedList pager)
{
    return PagedList.Mvc.HtmlHelper.PagedListPager(
        helper,
        pager,
        page =>
        {
            return Url.Action("Inspection", "Operation", new { page = page, pageList = true });
        },
        new PagedList.Mvc.PagedListRenderOptions()
        {
            LiElementClasses = new List<string> { "pagerLiElement" },
            ContainerDivClasses = new List<string> { },
            UlElementClasses = new List<string> { "pagerUlElementClasses" },
            DisplayPageCountAndCurrentLocation = false,
            DisplayLinkToFirstPage = PagedList.Mvc.PagedListDisplayMode.Always,
            DisplayLinkToLastPage = PagedList.Mvc.PagedListDisplayMode.Always,
            DisplayLinkToNextPage = PagedList.Mvc.PagedListDisplayMode.Always,
            DisplayLinkToPreviousPage = PagedList.Mvc.PagedListDisplayMode.Always,
            Display = PagedList.Mvc.PagedListDisplayMode.IfNeeded,
            LinkToLastPageFormat = "Last",
            LinkToNextPageFormat = "Next",
            LinkToPreviousPageFormat = "Prev",
            LinkToFirstPageFormat = "1st",
            DisplayEllipsesWhenNotShowingAllPageNumbers = true,
            MaximumPageNumbersToDisplay = 5,
            DisplayLinkToIndividualPages = true,
            ClassToApplyToFirstListItemInPager = "pagerLiElementFirst",
            ClassToApplyToLastListItemInPager = "pagerLiElement",
        }
    );
}
```

The css link that I will to add is:

```
<link href="~/Content/css/PageListCustom.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately that is not very easy to achieve. The CSS `<link>` tag must be in the `<head>` section as the [W3C documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#edef-LINK) specifies:

> This element defines a link. Unlike A, it may only appear in the HEAD section of a document, although it may appear any number of times. Although LINK has no content, it conveys relationship information that may be rendered by user agents in a variety of ways (e.g., a tool-bar with a drop-down menu of links).

This means you cannot just output it as part of your `HtmlHelper` string, because that will be used in the body of the HTML page. You must instead either add the CSS link manually to the `<head>` or use [inline `<style>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style) which is arguably less clean solution.